# HttpPostedFileBase pass to controller when clik on button,not a submit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

my view

```
<input type="file" data-val="true"  id="file" name="file" style="width: 200px;"  />
<input name="" type="button" value="Import file" class="Button_blue" id="ImportFile" />
```

IN my controller

```
public ActionResult BRSImport1(BRSImportModel objBRSImportModel, FormCollection fc, HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

when click on button HttpPostedFileBase has no file,it shows null,but button used as a submit it has file,but i want file when click on button

Comment: If you want to post the file without a submit button then you need to do it with ajax using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: Also, you can access the file via the FormCollection you pass into the action. Files have their own property on this object. Regarding the FormData, keep in mind that this wont work [in IE8 or IE9](http://caniuse.com/#search=formdata).